# Textbox is not losing previous values while updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm calling data from gridview control through `request.querystring` into textboxes. But when I edit the value textboxes does not update new values.

This is the page I'm calling data from:

```
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="dealowner" HeaderText="dealowner" SortExpression="dealowner" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="dealname" HeaderText="dealname" SortExpression="dealname" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="accountname" HeaderText="accountname" SortExpression="accountname" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="type" SortExpression="type" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="nextstep" HeaderText="nextstep" SortExpression="nextstep" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="leadsource" HeaderText="leadsource" SortExpression="leadsource" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="amount" SortExpression="amount" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="closingdate" HeaderText="closingdate" SortExpression="closingdate" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="stage" HeaderText="stage" SortExpression="stage" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="probability" HeaderText="probability" SortExpression="probability" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="expectedrevenue" HeaderText="expectedrevenue" SortExpression="expectedrevenue" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="campaignsource" HeaderText="campaignsource" SortExpression="campaignsource" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="description" SortExpression="description" />
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:staffshawConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Deals] WHERE [id] = @id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Deals] ([dealowner], [dealname], [accountname], [type], [nextstep], [leadsource], [amount], [closingdate], [stage], [probability], [expectedrevenue], [campaignsource], [description]) VALUES (@dealowner, @dealname, @accountname, @type, @nextstep, @leadsource, @amount, @closingdate, @stage, @probability, @expectedrevenue, @campaignsource, @description)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Deals]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Deals] SET [dealowner] = @dealowner, [dealname] = @dealname, [accountname] = @accountname, [type] = @type, [nextstep] = @nextstep, [leadsource] = @leadsource, [amount] = @amount, [closingdate] = @closingdate, [stage] = @stage, [probability] = @probability, [expectedrevenue] = @expectedrevenue, [campaignsource] = @campaignsource, [description] = @description WHERE [id] = @id">
                        <DeleteParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
                        </DeleteParameters>
                        <InsertParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="dealowner" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="dealname" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="accountname" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="nextstep" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="leadsource" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="amount" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="closingdate" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="stage" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="probability" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="expectedrevenue" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="campaignsource" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="description" Type="String" />
                        </InsertParameters>
                        <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="dealowner" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="dealname" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="accountname" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="type" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="nextstep" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="leadsource" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="amount" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="closingdate" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="stage" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="probability" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="expectedrevenue" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="campaignsource" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="description" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
                        </UpdateParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is the page I'm calling in:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style5"><strong>Deal Information</strong></td>
                <td class="auto-style5">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style5"></td>
                <td class="auto-style5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Deal Owner"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="dealowner" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Amount"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="amount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Deal Name"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="dealname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Closing Date"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="closingdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Account Name"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="accountname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Stage"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="stage" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>-None-</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Qualification</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Needs Analysis</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Value Proposition</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Identity Decision Makers</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Proposal/Price Quote</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Negotiation/Review</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Closed Won</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Closed Lost</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Closed-Lost to Competition</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Type"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="type" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>-None-</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Existing Business</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>New Businees</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Probability (%)"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="probability" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Next Step"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="nextstep" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Expected Revenue"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="expectedrevenue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Lead Source"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="leadsource" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>-None-</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Advertisment</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Cold Call</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Employee Referral</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>External Referral</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Online Store</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Partner</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Public Relations</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Sales Email Alias</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Seminar Partner</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Internal Seminar</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Trade Show</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Web Download</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Web Research</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Chat</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Campaign Source"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="campaignsource" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Contact Name"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="contactname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style4"></td>
                <td class="auto-style4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">Description Information</td>
                <td class="auto-style3"></td>
                <td class="auto-style3"></td>
                <td class="auto-style3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Description" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Edit" />
```

The page where data is coming from:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Deals.aspx");
        }

        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("EditDeals.aspx?id=" + ((LinkButton)sender).Text);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the page where data will be edited:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["staffshawConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string data = Request.QueryString["id"];
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Deals where id = '" + data + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    ID.Text = rdr["id"].ToString();
                    dealowner.Text = rdr["dealowner"].ToString();
                    accountname.Text = rdr["accountname"].ToString();
                    type.Text = rdr["type"].ToString();
                    nextstep.Text = rdr["nextstep"].ToString();
                    leadsource.Text = rdr["leadsource"].ToString();
                    amount.Text = rdr["amount"].ToString();
                    closingdate.Text = rdr["closingdate"].ToString();
                    stage.Text = rdr["stage"].ToString();
                    probability.Text = rdr["probability"].ToString();
                    expectedrevenue.Text = rdr["expectedrevenue"].ToString();
                    campaignsource.Text = rdr["campaignsource"].ToString();
                    Description.Text = rdr["description"].ToString();
                    dealname.Text = rdr["dealname"].ToString();

                }

            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Deals set  dealowner='"+dealowner.Text+ "',dealname='" + dealname.Text + "',accountname='" + accountname.Text + "',type='" + type.Text + "',nextstep='" + nextstep.Text + "',leadsource='" + leadsource.Text + "',amount='" + amount.Text + "',closingdate='" + closingdate.Text + "',stage='" + stage.Text + "',probability='" + probability.Text + "',expectedrevenue='" + expectedrevenue.Text + "',campaignsource='" + campaignsource.Text + "',description='" + Description.Text + "' where id ="+ID.Text+";", conn);
               // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update [pessenger_details]set pnr='" + pnr.Text + "', t_no='" + t_no.Text + "', name='" + name.Text + "', type='" + type.Text + "' where id= '" + id.Text + "'", con);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();

                Label1.Text = "Edit Successfully";
                Response.Redirect("AllDeals.aspx");





            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Response.Write(Ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was successfull to retreive data to another webform but cant edit it.

Comment: You are forming your SQL commands via string concatenation. That's not the source of your current problem, but it can result in errors if users put special characters in the text, and it is also a serious security violation because it leaves your app open to SQL Injection attacks. Please see [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) for more info about SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: so what is the best approach to do it ?

Comment: Use parameters and/or stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably only need to add a if (!Page.IsPostBack) somewhere.

When you click on a button, the page is firstly reloaded, then the event is triggered and lastly data are loaded back.

[See this link about Page Life Cycle](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/page-life-cycle-with-examples-in-Asp-Net/)

Try only loading at the first Page_load and not at every postback.

And as said, for sql statement, string concatenation isn't great unless you perfectly master what data are going to be in this string (and even if you think you do...).

You should consider using PreparedStatement